# EF Code First Detached Entity not updating object reference

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, stateless

I'm posting the exact entity:

```
    public class Person : ContactableEntity
{

    public Plan Plan { get; set; }

    public int Record { get; set; }

    public int PersonTypeValue { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using the following code to update in a disconected context fashion:

```
        public void Update(DbSet MySet, object Obj)
    {
        MySet.Attach(Obj);
        var Entry = this.Entry(Obj);
        Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is a method exposed by my dbContext
Called this way:

```
PersistentManager.Update(PersistentManager.Personas,UpdatedPersona);
```

The problem is, EF will update any property but the referenced Plan object.
Can someone tell me where is the mistake?
In advance : the entity reaches the point of update with all the properties correctly set.
EF just fails to update the FK in the Database (no exception though)
Update:
 tried solving the problem like this but it didn't work:

```
            PersistentMgr.Contacts.Attach(Obj);
            PersistentMgr.Entry(Obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            PersistentMgr.Entry(Obj.Plan).State = EntityState.Modified;
            PersistentMgr.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need...

```
this.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
this.Entry(person.Plan).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

...because when you set the state of the `person` to `Modified` the person gets attached to the context in state `Modified` but related entities like `person.Plan` are attached in state `Unchanged`.

If the relationship between `Person` and `Plan` has been changed while the entities were detached it is more difficult (especially, like in your model, when no foreign key is exposed as property ("independent association")) to update the entities correctly. You basically need to load the original object graph from the database, compare it with detached graph if relationships have been changed and merge the changes into the loaded graph. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237269/270591) (see the second code snippet in that answer).

**Edit**

Example to show that it works (with EF 5.0):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFModifyTest
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Plan Plan { get; set; }
        public int Record { get; set; }
        public int PersonTypeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Plan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeText { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());

            // Create a person with plan
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                ctx.Database.Initialize(true);

                var plan = new Plan { SomeText = "Old Text" };
                var person = new Person { Plan = plan, Record = 1, PersonTypeValue = 11 };

                ctx.Contacts.Add(person);

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            // see screenshot 1 from SQL Server Management Studio

            Person detachedPerson = null;
            // Load the person with plan
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                detachedPerson = ctx.Contacts.Include(c => c.Plan).First();
            }

            // Modify person and plan while they are detached
            detachedPerson.Record = 2;
            detachedPerson.PersonTypeValue = 12;
            detachedPerson.Plan.SomeText = "New Text";

            // Attach person and plan to new context and set their states to Modified
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                ctx.Entry(detachedPerson).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.Entry(detachedPerson.Plan).State = EntityState.Modified;

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            // see screenshot 2 from SQL Server Management Studio
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot 1 from SQL Server Management Studio (before the modification, `Person` table is left, `Plan` table is right):

[image: Before modification]

Screenshot 2 from SQL Server Management Studio (after the modification, `Person` table is left, `Plan` table is right):

[image: After modification]

If it doesn't work for you there must be an important difference to my test model and code. I don't know which one, you must provide more details.

**Edit 2**

If you change the relationship from `Person` to another (existing) `Plan` you must load the original and then update the relationship. With independent associations (no FK property in model) you can update relationships only by using change tracking (aside from more advanced modifications of relationship entries in the `ObjectContext` change tracker):

```
var originalPerson = this.Contacts.Include(c => c.Plan)
    .Single(c => c.Id == person.Id);
this.Plans.Attach(person.Plan);

this.Entry(originalPerson).CurrentValues.SetValues(person);
originalPerson.Plan = person.Plan;

this.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP would then have to create a separate Update method for every different entity type. The example method that they posted just took an object.

Comment: @luksan: Yes, I know, but I cannot make use of this method. He **has** to write a separate Update method for every entity type (at least when related entities are involved), even maybe multiple Update methods per entity, depending on the kind of Update. Do you know how to perform such a super-generic Update that only needs an `object` and four lines of code and can handle all possible relationship changes for every entity and related entities and collections and nested stuff and so on?

Comment: No, I don't. Entity Framework should handle it automatically... but it doesn't.

Comment: I don't have a problem with that... I know EF it's not supposed to be used this way, but the architecture was defined a long time ago...
I used this code::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                                            
`PersistentMgr.Contacts.Attach(Obj);:::::::::::::::::
PersistentMgr.Entry(Obj).State = EntityState.Modified;::::::::::
PersistentMgr.Entry(Obj.Plan).State = EntityState.Modified;:::::::::
PersistentMgr.SaveChanges();`
It didn't work either

Comment: @Alvaro: See my Edit above. I've made a test model and program to show that is "normally" works. There must be some important difference in your model or code that causes the update to fail in your situation. But which one?

Comment: The problem is, that's a change in the Plan table.. What EF doesn't do is change the FK in Persons . I want to reference another "Plan"
The strange thing is, I have another entity who uses a Plan atribute, and it updates just fine

Comment: INDEED i just did that a moment ago and it worked! SUCKS to have to do a query though

Comment: @Alvaro: If you introduce a foreign key property `PlanId` in `Person` it would work without a query.

Comment: I thought the exact same thing, but the model is a little intrincated and the SQL server throws an exception of circular dependencies when creating the FK restriction.
This helps a LOT since I didn't get why sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.
Thanks!