# Entity Framework aggregate root update

Tags: entity-framework, aggregate

I use entity framework eager load approach since I have to provide the client the  whole hierarchy. 
On the way back I can see that the object in the context is identical to the object that the client returned (I assume that the context is updated with that object although it doesn't manage the entries state). 
Question #1 - 
Do I have to bring the "old" entity from the DB and start comparing? (A hit to the db...)
Question #2 -
I have read the solution given by Slauma in [Entity framework, problems updating related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236116/entity-framework-problems-updating-related-objects) discussion. 
Do you realy have to do all the comparison logics between both objects? 
Question #2.1 -
Can't you avoid code like

```
// Update subFoos that are in the newFoo.SubFoo collection
context.Entry(dbSubFoo).CurrentValues.SetValues(newSubFoo);
```

The code suggested there is a nightmare to write and maintain.
I would really appreciate advice for that situation. 
Something that maybe won't be elegant but it least reasonable.

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? Can you keep the entity attached to the context while client is using it?

Comment: It's web and the object is serialized to json back and forth. Context won't do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will help someone. 
The following project (there is also nuget package) provide elegant way for graph update.
It works very well even in complicated scenarios.

Github: 
https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff

Examples:
http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/

Nuget:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/

Another option is to implement IComparable at the object level and use it in the update logic in comparison to an entity from the DB.