# How to save changes to related table in MVC 5 and EF 6 - Entity Framework Master-Detail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables, Promotion and PromotionLine, with a foreign key defined as PromotionLine.PromoID = Promotion.ID

PromotionLines are associated with the Promotion model with the following in the Promotion class:

```
public IList<PromotionLine> PromotionLineItems { get; set; }
```

I chose not to use virtual because I don't want the promo lines loaded if we're just using a summary view to show high level Promotion info (such as a list of Promotions).

When promotion details are needed, I get the promotion lines:

```
    public static Promotion GetInstance(int? promotionId)
    {
        if (promotionId == null) return null;
        using (APP01Entities entities = new APP01Entities())
        {
            return entities.Promotions
                .Include(s => s.PromotionState)
                .Include(h => h.PromotionHeaderType)
                .Include(l => l.PromotionLineItems)
                .Include(c => c.PromotionComments)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == promotionId);
        }

    }
```

This works, and I can access the promotion lines in my view.

However, when I go to update changes, I encounter the error:

> “A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   value(s) of 'Promotion.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match
>   the property value(s) of 'PromotionLine.PromotionID' on the other
>   end.”

I understand WHY this error is occurring.  I don't know how to get around it.
I'm using the default update method (created by EF scaffolding):

```
public bool Update()
    {
        try
        {
            using (APP01Entities entities = new APP01Entities())
            {
                entities.Promotions.Attach(this);

                var entity = entities.ChangeTracker.Entries<Promotion>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Entity == this);

                if (entity == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entities.SaveChanges();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            throw e.Improve();
        }
    }
```

**The problem is with:**

```
entities.Promotions.Attach(this);
```

"this" has the promotion lines.  entities.Promotions does not.

Here is how I'm calling the update method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Promotion promotion)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            promotion.Update();
        }
        return View(promotion);
    }
```

**Questions**

- How do I get the promotion lines added to entities.Promotions?
- or, should I be approaching this update differently?

Comment: What is your Promotion Edit template like?

Comment: Have child lists been changed? for example some item added to `PromotionLineItems` and some item of `PromotionComments` removed and ...?

Comment: @RezaAghaei - yes, child lists have changed (for example, values in PromotionLineItems have changed).

Comment: Only changes or maybe added and removed also?

Comment: I posted a long answer for you, this is the way that I use and it works properly. You should get the main idea that I described in steps and then try to change the code to match your entities. I performed the job only for one of child properties and when you can solve the problem for one of properties, you can solve the problem for all of child properties. Hope you find it helpful:)

Comment: @devlincarnate Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13236116/861716). Keep in mind that marking an entity as `Modified` only affects its scalar properties (same as `CurrentValues.SetValues`) and you'll see why this question is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: @GertArnold - that post did the trick.  I spent 2 days researching this question before posting the question, so thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a trivial task. You need to update your object graph. In other word you need a Master-Detail update.

To keep the answer simple I suppose I have an `Order` entity that have `OrderDetails` property that is a `List<OrderDetail>`.You should pay attention when editing:

- There are some `OrderDetail` that have been added to `OrderDetails` and the main sign of them is having `Id` property equal to 0.
- Some `OrderDetail` have been removed and no longer exist in `OrderDetails`
- Some `OrderDetail` have been changed.

When updating the `Order` you should update the `Order` itself and also apply above changes.

**Steps**

Here are steps:

1. Get original order from database.
2. Update the value of original order using edited order.
3. Find list of added items (Id of added items is 0).
4. Find list of removed items (list of order details of original order where id of original order details is not between ids of order details of edited order).
5. Find list of edited items (list of order details of original order where id of original order details is between ids of order details of edited order).
6. Use a loop over deleted items list and set state of them to removed.
7. Use a loop over edited items list and update value of original order details  that have been loaded in context.
8. Use a loop over added items list and set state of them to added.
9. Set the state of original order to modified.
10. Save context changes.

**Code**

Here is the code:

```
public void Update(Order editedOrder)
{
    using(var context = new YourDbContext())
    {   
        //Get original order from database.
        var originalOrder = context.Orders.Including("OrderDetails")
            .Where(x => x.OrderId == editedOrder.OrderId).FirstOrDefault();

        //Update the value of original order using edited order.
        context.Entry(originalOrder).CurrentValues.SetValues(editedOrder);

        //Find list of added items (Id of added items is 0).
        var addedList = editedOrder.OrderDetails
            .Where(y => y.OrderDetailId == 0).ToList();

        //Find list of removed items.
        var deletedList = originalOrder.OrderDetails
            .Where
            (
                x =>!editedOrder.OrderDetails.Select(y => y.OrderDetailId)
                        .Contains(x.OrderDetailId)
            )
            .ToList();

        //Find list of edited items.
        var editedList = editedOrder.OrderDetails
            .Where
            (
                y => originalOrder.OrderDetails.Select(z => z.OrderDetailId)
                         .Contains(y.OrderDetailId)
            )
            .ToList();

        //Use a loop over deleted items list and set state of them to removed.
        deletedList.ForEach(deletedDetail =>
        {
            originalOrder.OrderDetails.Remove(deletedDetail);
            context.Entry(editedOrder).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        });

        //Use a loop over edited items list 
        //and update value of original order details  that have been loaded in context.
        editedList.ForEach(editedDetail =>
        {
            var originalOrderDetail = originalOrder.OrderDetails
                .Where(x => x.OrderDetailId == editedDetail.OrderDetailId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
           context.Entry(originalOrderDetail).CurrentValues.SetValues(editedDetail);
        });

        //Use a loop over added items list and set state of them to added.
        addedList.ForEach(addedDetail =>
        {
            originalOrder.OrderDetails.Add(addedDetail);
        });

        //Set the state of original order to modified.
        context.Entry(oroginalOrder).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        //Save context changes.
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the link Gert provided in the question comments, but this is a similar approach.  I'm marking it as the answer because I believe it will help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback:)