# Complex C# Object Cascading Update

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have the following:

```
// Day Class
public class Day {
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playlists")]
    public virtual List < Playlist > playlists { get; set; }
}

// Schedule Class
public class Schedule {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual List < Day > days { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string hash { get; set; }
}

// Playlist Class
public class Playlist {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("media")]
    public virtual List < Media > media { get; set; }

    // Media class
    public class Media {
        ...
    }
```

I am using Web API, SQL / EF to create CRUD operations on the above classes.
However, my issue is that when I POST to `/schedules/` I'd like all the related properties to update. I am POSTING a raw JSON object and I can parse it properly. The problem is that if I have a `media` object in the database with a `unique` key `hash` or any other object in the db the POST fails with a key duplicate exception since it is trying to re-add the object. I'd like to update the relationships in that scenario... What should I be doing to correct this?

Please ask if you need any other info.
Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

```
  [ResponseType(typeof(Schedule))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSchedule([FromBody]Object model)
        {
            var jsonSchedule = model.ToString();
            try
            {
                var _schedule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Schedule>(jsonSchedule);

                db.Schedules.Add(_schedule);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return Ok();
            }
```

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I've updated the question.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya It does... This works as expected

Comment: If you are editing the parent and and adding/editing/deleting child items at the same time, you need to update your object graph and its not a trivial task. You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33509039/3110834) helpful.

Comment: Also you are using `db.Schedules.Add` that tries to insert the entity and all it's children to database.

Comment: You should get your entity from the database (with the id) and then update it with the new values. This way your entity remain attached to the DbContext.

Comment: @RezaAghaei The answer seems very helpful. However, I have two other layers (nested objects), what should I do in this case?

Comment: If you are only editing child items in all levels, you can simply mark them as edited. But if you add/edit/delete in all levels, the case is really complicated and you should follow such approach that I did step by step in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33509039/3110834)

Comment: You can avoid such complicated edit if you use ajax and commit changes on each request (add/edit/delete).

Comment: By the way, it would be great if you kindly vote for that answer, if you find that helpful. This way that will be more useful for future readers.

Comment: @RezaAghaei sure I will, could you please elaborate a bit on using ajax on each request? You mean I handle relationships using separate calls?

Comment: @RezaAghaei also please note that in my case i'm posting the initial object initially so it doesn't exist in the database yet.

Comment: So you can show `Day` page and let the user enter the name and click save, after the user clicked save, you can save the day in database and show an empty list of `Schedules` that the user can click add for it, and when he clicked add, you can show a dialog to him to enter schedule fields and let him save. After he saved, he can add `Playlist` or edit the `Schedule` or delete the `Schedule` or add new `Schedule`. Continue this pattern until the end of your graph.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thing is, Media objects already exist in the database... I need to do handle the relationship updates programatically...

Comment: No problem, Follow that pattern, and let the user choose media items from an autocomplete or dropdownlist. If you follow such pattern, then the question would be **How to add an existing media item to an existing playlist** and the answer will be **simply load both of them, then `playlist.media.Add(existingMedia)` then `db.SaveChanges()`**