# Update rows from included table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select

I use EF 6. I select row from the `users` table and use `.Include` to also get the **address** (etc...). Now I want update that address data.

How can I do it?

This code updates only the `users` table:

```
var MyUser = db.Users.Include(b => b.Address)
                     .Where(x => x.MISPAR_ZIHUY.Equals(123456))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
db.Users.Attach(MyUser);
db.Entry(MyUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(MyUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(MyNewUser);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: var MyUser= db.Users.Select(b => b.Address).Where(x => x.MISPAR_ZIHUY.Equals(123456))
That if i understand your question right

Comment: db.Users has an AcceptChanges() method which writes data back to the database.

Comment: aya-abdelaziz - Did you mean remove .FirstOrDefault() ?

Comment: jdweng - I use SaveChanges()

Comment: i mean use Select instead of include to select all address

Comment: But I need to get also the dependency tables of users and update them.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate issue. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236116/entity-framework-problems-updating-related-objects) If you want to set nested entities (I.e. addresses within a User) based on the provided modified set, you need to call SetValues() on each nested entity.

Comment: Because I want to replace MyUser with MyNewUser